# How to convert 7:30 AM time to javascript Date type?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timepicker

How can I convert time taken from form in html in the format of Hours:Minutes AM/PM to Date class object in javascript.

Comment: You need to try something. You might start by splitting the time into hours and minutes, then create a `new Date()` and use [*setHours*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.sethours) to set the time.

Comment: Have a look at the `SimpleDateFormat` class for parsing date/time

Comment: Java ! = Javascript. Are you asking about doing this in server-side Java?

Comment: JavaScript only.! @nnnnnn

Comment: Probably should [edit] your question title then. (Also Javascript doesn't have a Date *class* per se, it has Date objects, but I guess we know what you mean now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex to parse the time and set it to a date object.

```
var d = new Date(),
    s ='7:30 AM',
    parts = s.match(/(\d+)\:(\d+) (\w+)/),
    hours = /am/i.test(parts[3]) ? parseInt(parts[1], 10) : parseInt(parts[1], 10) + 12,
    minutes = parseInt(parts[2], 10);

d.setHours(hours, minutes,0,0); // As suggested by @RobG
// d.setHours(hours);
// d.setMinutes(minutes);

console.log(d);
```

Comment: You can do `d.setHours(hours, minutes,0,0)`. Saves a bit of typing. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have your input in the form `var time = "7:30 AM"`.

The first thing we want to do is get the AM/PM out of the way.

`time.split(' ')` gives us `["7:30", "AM"]`, so we do:

```
var timePeriod = time.split(' ')[1];
time = time.split(' ')[0];
```

*See [MDN's article on .split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)  if you have any questions*

We now have `timePeriod === 'AM'` and `time === '7:30'`.

We can use the same trick to get hour and minute.

```
var hour = time.split(':')[0];
var minute = time.split(':')[1];
```

It would be easier to just use numbers, so we'll normalize our data a bit here.

```
if (timePeriod === 'AM') {
    // Do not use `hour += 12` here as that will not convert the result to a number
    hour = 12 + hour
}
```

And now we just have numbers to work with. Let's start with the current date:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
```

and modify the hour and minute to match the data we just parsed:

```
currentDate.setHours(hour);
currentDate.setMinutes(minute);
```

Now we should have a date that we can work with!

*See [MDN's article on the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) if you have any questions******

Comment: Given "7:30 AM" then `hour += 12` will evaluate to "712". ;-)